# How to show that the angle is given by

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

[Translation of the figure/picture: A) show that the angle u is given by:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89mV3.png) 
$y$ is the segment for $BD$, $x$ is the segment for $BC$ and $a$ is the segment for $AB$

How do I show that the angle $u = arctan\frac{y}{a}-arctan\frac{x}{a}$?

I know that $tanu = \frac{x}{a}$ so $u=arctan\frac{x}{a}$ and that $u=tan\frac{y}{a}$ I need a better explanation cause i'm pretty confused.

Comment: You don't have $\tan u=x/a$ nor $\tan u=y/a$, because $DAC$ is not a right triangle. Consider instead triangles $BAD$ and $BAC$.

Comment: @aretino but we dont know about the hypotenous, and thus we cannot use sine or cosine. So only option left is tanget?

Comment: @Aretino I mean like, from $AB = a$, $ BC = x$ and $BD = y$ so we can use the triangle with the 90 degree angle, and then use $BAD$. So that we get $AB = Adejcent side$ and $BC = Opposite side$ and then for the "other one" we can use the same Adejcent side and this time we can use $BD$ as the opposite side. Giving us the tan

Comment: HINT: $u=\angle DAB -\angle CAB$.

Comment: @Aretino Yeah I know, that's what I just kinda said in my previous comment. But Why do we subtract them?

Comment: That's the definition of angle subtraction.